# How to avoid "TypeError: argument 2 must be a connection, cursor or None" with SQLAlchemy/psycopg2 when creating engine from engine_from_config()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, alembic, aws-xray

After patching psycopg2 with the latest aws-xray-python-sdk (v2.2.0), my alembic script started to throw exception : TypeError: argument 2 must be a connection, cursor or None.

The [`TypeError: argument 2 must be a connection, cursor or None` in Psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40271083/typeerror-argument-2-must-be-a-connection-cursor-or-none-in-psycopg2) thread seems to indicate that setting a proper creator when creating the engine using sqlalchemy.create_engine would solve this problem.

However, I currently use engine_from_config() to create my sqlalchemy engine.

Anyway to specify the creator or solve this issue while using engine_from_config()?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like this might be related https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-python/pull/95 as the PR removes the X-Ray code path when SQLAlchemy register extensions.

Comment: Spot on! I will wait for the PR then. Thanks!

Comment: The PR has been merged to the dev version. You can use it by using git+git://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-python@5b35427b71e527132ad5afdd3110e103619fb87a#egg=aws-xray-sdk
 in your requirement.txt